# strcmp() returns 0 when comparing to unequal strings

Tags: c, string, palindrome, strcmp

In C, strcmp() function returns 0 if two strings are equal.
When I give a code like this,

```
char str[10] = "hello";
if(strcmp(str,strrev(str))==0)
{
printf("1");
}
else
printf("0");
```

This should print a 1 if its a palindromic string or it should print 0 if it is not a palindrome.
But it prints 1 even when the given string "hello" is not a palindrome. Where is the mistake?

Comment: read documentation on functions you attemp to use first. strrev seems to revert given string and not creating new one. End of story.

Comment: Rather than conclude "strcmp() returns 0 when comparing to unequal strings", consider `strcmp()` has been around for 40+ years and is working correct.  Ask "Why are strings `str` and `strrev(str)` equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strrev()` is not a standatd C library function.

*Your* `strrev()` is reversing the actual string `str` first, then going for `strcmp()` with the changed string. So the results are always equal.

If you want to have the desired result:

1. make a copy of the original string
2. pass the original string to `strrev()`
3. compare with the earlier copy.

Answer (score 6):

What is `strrev()`? That's not a standard C function.

My assumption would be that it doesn't work like you think it does, i.e. it doesn't create and return a new heap copy of the string. Of course, *if* you expect that, then there's a bug that you don't retain the returned pointer so you can `free()` it when you're done.

Basically, you seem to expect C strings to behave like strings in a higher-level language, which they really don't.